# Несоответствие типа возвращаемого веб-методом

Tags: asp.net

Почему при возвращении значения из веб-метода тип возвращаемого значения изменяется. На примере показанном ниже, список возвращаемый из веб-метода приходится изменять на массив, иначе выходит ошибка: "*Неявное преобразование типа "localhost.SearchResults[]" в "System.Collections.Generic.List<localhost.SearchResults>" невозможно*"

```
// Default.aspx
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    localhost.WebService ws = new localhost.WebService();

    // Если написать так выходит ошибка
    List<localhost.SearchResults> results = ws.Query(TextQuery.Text);

    localhost.SearchResults[] = ws.Query(TextQuery.Text); 
}

// WebService.asmx
[WebMethod]
public List<SearchResults> Query(string query)
{
    Searcher searcher = new Searcher();
    return searcher.Query(query);
}
```

Comment: Нет вы не поняли. Если я укажу в Default.aspx List<localhost.SearchResults> results = ws.Query(TextQuery.Text) то выходит ошибка несоответствия типа указанная выше.

Comment: нет это вы не поняли - если метод возвращает массив, то почему он должен кастоваться к списку?

Answer (score 1):

и в чем проблема? Для вас является сюрпризом тот факт, что List<T> и T[] - разные типы?

Если так уж надо, то можете вызвать метод ToList(), который является методом расширения (соответственно, вам надо будет подключить пространство имен Linq)

Comment: Все нашел свою ошибку. Я пытался кастовать значение возвращаемое из метода Query, а надо было в самом Default.aspx написать так List<localhost.SearchResults> results = ws.Query(TextQuery.Text).ToList(). А почему вообще возвращается массив вместо списка. Разве веб-методы не поддерживают списки?